# Can I scrape content only after a specific header?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
def parse_linkpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = QualificationItem()
    xpath = """
            //h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
             /following-sibling::p
            """
    item['Qualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()[1:]
    item['Country'] = response.meta['a_of_the_link']
    return item
```

So I was wondering if I could get my code to stop scraping after reaching the end of the `<h2>`.

Here is the webpage:

```
<h2>Entry requirements for undergraduate courses</h2>
<p>Example1</p>
<p>Example2</p>
<h2>Postgraduate Courses</h2>
<p>Example3</p>
<p>Example4</p>
```

I want these results:

```
Example1
Example2
```

But I get:

```
Example1
Example2
Example3
Example4
```

I know I could change this line,

```
item['Qualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()
```

to,

```
item['Qualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()[0:2]
```

But this scraper looks at many different pages that might have more than 2 paragraphs in the first header meaning it would leave this information out.

I'm wondering if there is a way of just telling it to extract the exact data that follows the header I want and not everything?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very pretty or easy to read, but you can use EXSLT extensions to XPath and use `set:difference()` operation:

```
>>> selector.xpath("""
    set:difference(//h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
                    /following-sibling::p,
                   //h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
                    /following-sibling::h2[1]
                    /following-sibling::p)""").extract()
[u'<p>Example1</p>', u'<p>Example2</p>']
```

The idea is to select all `p` following your target `h2`, and exclude those `p` that are after the next `h2`

In a bit easier to read version:

```
>>> for h2 in selector.xpath('//h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]'):
...     paragraphs = h2.xpath("""set:difference(./following-sibling::p,
...                                             ./following-sibling::h2[1]/following-sibling::p)""").extract()
...     print paragraphs
... 
[u'<p>Example1</p>', u'<p>Example2</p>']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this xpath

```
//h2[normalize-space(.)="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"]
         /following-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::h2[normalize-space(.)!="Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"])]
```

you can just add another predicate of the `following-sibling::p` not to include those `p`s whose preceding-sibling is not equal to "Entry requirements for undergraduate courses"